# Python 3.10.4 SpeechRecognition 3.9.0 AudioSource and AttributeError while using Microphone

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio, microphone

I try to play around with speech recognition, this is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

# device_index=1
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something")
    audio = r.listen(source) # <- Error
    
    try:
        voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(voice_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When I run the outcome is:

```
Say something
AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I install PyAudio 0.2.11 from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) since the problems (but also tried with pip install). I also tried to change

```
with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
```

Sadly same error..

Answer (score 0):

I notice two differences between your code and my working code.

1. Try setting the pause threshold before grabbing the audio with the r.listen(source) like this: r.pause_threshold = 1.0.
2. The second is in your try block when you set the voice_data variable and use the r.recognize_google(audio). In my working code, I specify language='EN-US' as a second parameter like this: r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us').